# Excel IF statements, with 3 conditions if a=true and b=true and c=true then d1 = ""

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to make an excel formula so that, I can test out 3 columns and if they are true then to set a new value to the 4rth column.

I have this formula:

```
=IF(AND(A1="ALFA ROMEO"; B1="159"; C1="55");D1="2016";D1="")
```

and I want to check if A1 and B1 and C1 are true then to set D1 equal to a certain value.

*I've tried many complex ways to achieve it but this formula is the only one that doesnt pop up an error, but still gives back the Value FALSE(Not in D1, but in the cell I tried it). I've also tried seperating with commas etc...

Any possible help or way I could achieve the check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should come from the quote ("") around the number
I've try this

> =SI(ET(A1="ALFA ROMEO";B1=159;C1=55);2016;"")

and it worked for me (sorry it's in french).

Maybe try to change cell format from the column B and C.
And also put the formula in cell D1 or in the cell you want the value.

Comment: I found the documentation behind the formulas here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-functions-by-category-5f91f4e9-7b42-46d2-9bd1-63f26a86c0eb

Answer (score 3):

You're almost there, but you need to put this formula here **in cell D1** in order to fill the value of D1:

```
=IF(AND(A1="ALFA ROMEO", B1=159, C1=55),2016,"")
```

Keep out: in my locale I'm working with commas, while you might be working with semicolons, so your actual formula might be (**in cell D1**):

```
=IF(AND(A1="ALFA ROMEO"; B1=159; C1=55);2016;"")
```

Also, no need to put numerical values (159, 55) as strings, as you can see.

**Edit: about turning B1 into a string:**

I've just created this formula:

```
=IF(TEXT(B1,"0")="159","TRUE","FALSE")
```

This allows you to convert B1 into text.

So, your formula might turn into something like:

```
=IF(AND(A1="ALFA ROMEO", TEXT(B1, "0")="159", TEXT(C1,"0")="55"),2016,"")
```

(Again, mind the locale settings (commas and semicolons))

Comment: That worked perfectly, but how can I make this work, even when I include the Quotes when using an INT value?

Comment: @PeriklisKakarakidis: I've edited my question accordingly. Apparently, in order to convert a normal number into text, you might use the `TEXT(...)` function, using `"0"` as format specifier.

Comment: thank you for your help, everything works prerfectly now!